# What to do with a JSON Object Response?

Tags: php, json

I was working with Google Oauth 2 and finally was able to get the access token. Google simply returned the access token in a JSON object. The output was printed out on my browser. Since I've never touched JSON or any other API before, I have no idea how to capture that JSON object so I can store the access token.

Example Output(obscured the actual data)

```
{
"access_token":"1/6GKFqrOr6000000004k10qgr000000GiUiRNbLnc",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":3600,
"refresh_token": "1/Vx34LfPISDuX000000Kq_SJWIgf42FVs"
}
```

I tried the simple $token = $_POST['access_token']; which didn't work. json_decode also didn't work. I'm pretty sure I'm not doing it right here. Can someone tell me how you can interact with JSON object?

EDIT:

I guess my initial question is more rudimentary because I'm really new at API programming. What I want to know is how to encapsulate the browser response of a JSON object into a variable so my PHP script can dynamically decode the response. Currently, the browser just replied the content of the JSON object like I posted above but I don't know the object name or variable name like $object = {}. Is there any way to find out the object name or a way to put the response into an object or array dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

```
{
"access_token":"1/6GKFqrOr6000000004k10qgr000000GiUiRNbLnc",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":3600,
"refresh_token": "1/Vx34LfPISDuX000000Kq_SJWIgf42FVs"
}
```

Put this complete response in Json Object : Then JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);

Now get your access token: String value= jObject.getString("access_token");
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)($output,true). If you give the second parameter it will return an associative array.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this and it worked like a charm:

```
 $f = <<<HER
 {
 "access_token":"1/6GKFqrOr6000000004k10qgr000000GiUiRNbLnc",
 "token_type":"Bearer",
 "expires_in":3600,
 "refresh_token": "1/Vx34LfPISDuX000000Kq_SJWIgf42FVs"
 }
 HER;
 $c = json_decode($f);
 echo $c->access_token;
```

Were you trying to access the property like it was an array? In this case `$c['access_token']` would fail -- $c is not an array, it is an object. This is why I just used `$c->access_token;` to output the result. If you'd like, you can pass TRUE as the second parameter to json_decode, but truth be told, I don't know if that is really necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess my initial question is more rudimentary than you answer because I'm really new at API programming. What I want to know is how to encapsulate the browser response of a JSON object into a variable so my PHP script can dynamically decode the response. I can put it into a HERETYPE like you did but the output will be static... Currently, the browser just replied the content of the JSON object like  I posted above but I don't know the object name or variable name like $object = {}

Comment: I just put it in a HEREDOC because it is easier to test it. You're either going to need to send it as a $_GET or (more likely) $_POST and then use json_decode on the value in the input array.